# Angular Bootstrap collapse not firing even though $scope says it should

Tags: angularjs

Angular newbie here, running Angular 1.3 & ui-bootstrap 0.12. I'm just trying to learn Angular and ui-bootstrap and am unsure why the Angular Bootstrap collapse directive is not collapsing my div. Clicking on the buttons correctly toggles $scope.rightPanelCollapse yet the collapse is not happening.

Here's my markup:

```
<body ng-app="uxf.site">

<div class="container-fluid" data-ng-controller="UxfSiteController">

    <button data-ng-click="toggleRightPanelCollapse()">{{rightPanelCollapse}}</button>
    <button data-ng-click="toggleRightPanelCollapse()">{{rightPanelCollapse}}</button>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="left-panel" class="col-md-1 grid">
            {{rightPanelCollapse}}
        </div>
        <div id="content" class="col-md-10 col grid">
            {{rightPanelCollapse}}
        </div>
        <div id="right-panel" collapse="rightPanelCollapse">
            {{rightPanelCollapse}}
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Here's my JS:

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('uxf.site', [])
    .controller('UxfSiteController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.rightPanelCollapse = true;
      $scope.toggleRightPanelCollapse = function() {
        $scope.rightPanelCollapse = !$scope.rightPanelCollapse;
      };
    }]);
})(window.angular);
```

Comment: And your fiddle/plunker/codepen is...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...newbie move. I just forget to add ui.bootstrap.collapse as a dependency in my uxf.site module. Problem solved.